# Exploiting Stack Buffer Overflow

Tags: c, x86, buffer-overflow

First off the computer I'm running this on is an Intel System running Linux on a 32-bit stack. My professor posed a challenge question to us in class.

Here is the code before I ask the question

```
// funWithFooAndBar.c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

void bar() 
{ 
 printf("Now inside bar()!\n"); 
} 

void foo() 
{ 
 void *addr[1]; 

 printf("Now inside foo()!\n"); 
 // this is where I need to modify my code, 
 //I was given the hint that it will only be two lines of code 
 // So something like: 
addr[1] = bar;
addr[5] = addr[4];
addr[4] = bar;;

} 

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
 foo(); 
 printf("Back in main\n"); 
 return 0; 
}
```

The goal is to smash the stack by writing beyond the end of an array, and through that,  overwrite the return address so that the function call to foo () returns to bar () on its way back to main. So my output is supposed to look like:

Now inside foo() !

Now inside bar() !

Back in main

In order to do this I have to overflow the array so that the return address is overwritten with the address of the bar.I'm pretty sure that it will have to involve the address of function bar() which will equate to &bar()

The question he posed was what two lines of code could we add (where I commented) to make the output as a shown above.

Thanks!

Edit: I was hoping more for an explanation than a direct answer, I know what I'm supposed to do, just not how to translate that to the c code.

Edit: made an attempt

Comment: I was hoping more for an explanation than a direct answer, I know what I'm supposed to do, just not how to translate that to the c code.

Comment: so make an attempt.....

Comment: That obviously won't work since you wrote in memory you are allowed to.

Comment: Changed my attempt after reading the article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the article that R M linked:

addr[1] = bar;

addr[5] = addr[4];

addr[4] = bar;

Turns out to work.